# android eclipse button OnClick event

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-layout

I have 2 files: main_activity.xml and home.xml. I made a button in main_activity.xml

Here is the code snippet:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/splash_background"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Home"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="43dp"
    android:onClick="home"
    android:text="Home" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And then, I have my home.xml. I want the button to open up home.xml. How can i do this?
I don't know any java and I am new to android development.

Here is my home.xml below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/app_bg"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


</LinearLayout>
```

And below is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.example.idozer"
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0" >

 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

 <application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.idozer.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.example.idozer.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

And that's all I have. Please, if you reply, tell me where to add the code such as the directory or between code snippets.

Comment: Unless you use something like MonoDroid or some other app building alternative, Java is a pretty fundamental requirement for developing Android apps.  If you don't know Java then I suggest you learn that first.

Answer (score 8):

For managing click activity in android ,you can do as below

1. Implement `OnClickListener` on **YourActivity.java** class like

   `public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener`
2. Then, declare your button in .java class like

   `Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);`
3. Then use button `btn` variable as below

   ```
   btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       public void onClick(View v) {
           myClick(v); /* my method to call new intent or activity */
       }
   });
   ```
4. Handle the click event:

   ```
   public void myClick(View v) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(**this, Swipe.class**);
       startActivity(intent);// for calling the activity
   }
   ```

you also need to register your activity(.java) in `android manifest` as below

```
<activity
    android:name=".Swipe"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
</activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

> You can use this code.
>
> ### Android: OnClickListener

**In our activity class we add the onclick method.**

> In our activity class we add the onclick method.

```
    //On click event for button1
public void button1OnClick(View v) {
    //Inform the user the button has been clicked
    Toast.makeText(this, "Button1 clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();               
}
```

> In the layout file we add a reference to the onclick handler in the
>   activity. The app will automatically bind the onclick method to the
>   view (in this case button1)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button1"
            android:onClick="button1OnClick"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

create another class goto your project right click and click class and create Home. 
In that Home class file  extends activity and add code like this

```
public class Home extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);
  }
}
```

in **splash activity class** add this line

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,Home.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

add Home activity class in your android manifest file

```
<activity android:name="com.example.idozer.Home"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
```

Comment: Don't use int, its a reserved word in Java and probably nearly every other language ;)

Comment: No problem, that's better :)

Comment: @codeMagic the op is off line and im having a bit of a problem with this . if u have team viwer can u help me out ? ill post my session information here

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't right now. You should have enough to get you started. I can try and answer any questions you might have later

Comment: @codeMagic in splash activity class add this line . this confuses me because i dont know what u mean for me to do i dont have any file named that.

Comment: @user1978141 That's because I didn't write this answer. I merely made a comment on it to make it more correct. Please see my answer which I believe gives necessary links to help you understand what to do and descriptive information

Answer (score 0):

`android:onClick` was added in API level 4 to make it easier, more Javascript-web-like, and drive everything from the XML. What it does internally is add an `OnClickListener` on the `Button`, which calls your home method.

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/Home"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:layout_marginRight="43dp"
  android:onClick="home"
  android:text="Home" />
```

.

```
public void home(View view){
  Intent intent=new Intent (view.getContext(),Luton.class);
  this.startActivity(intent);
}
```

In your activity class

Using java code you can do button click by getting the id of the button from xml.

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/myHomeButton"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:layout_marginRight="43dp"
  android:text="Home" />
```

.

```
Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.myHomeButton);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
     //do whatever you want on button click
  }
});
```

Both are exactly the same

Comment: Close, but you wouldn't want `android:onClick="home" if you are implementing the `onClickListener` programmatically. It will be looking for a function with the signature `public void home(View v)`

Comment: I gave 2 ways do the same. Either use the 1st one or the second. However i recommend doing it the 2nd way (programatically calling button listener)

Comment: I understand but you have `android:onClick="home"` in both. I'm saying if you do the second way(programmatically) then you don't want that line in the xml. Which way to do it really depends on what you are doing with it. Yes, it seems to be the most popular and probably normally the "best" choice but I use both depending on what I am doing with it

Comment: @codeMagic agreed i removed the line form xml for the 2nd way.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you just a little bit to get you started as this answer may help others that are having trouble with using `onClick()` this way but you really need to learn Java and go through the **[Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/index.html)** so you can ask better questions

You need to read [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) about `Actviities` and how to create them. Then in your code you will have a function

```
 public void home(View v)  //the name of this function comes from where you declared in your manifest `android:onClick="home"
{
     Intent intent (MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class); //MainActivity is the name of current activity and HomeActivity is the name of the activity you want to start
     can add intent extras/flags/categories here
     startActivity(intent);
}
```

You also need to add the `HomeActivity` in your `manifest` as you have for the other `Activities`.

But you really need to go through the docs and do some tutorials to get an idea of how the Android framework operates and you need to learn Java to make your life a whole lot easier. Besides the previous two links I have given, also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15059351/using-nested-interfaces-for-communication-between-two-classes-in-java-android/15059793#15059793) about click events as there are different ways to use `onClick()`

I hope this is enough to get you started and I really hope you go through the docs to get a better understanding of what you are doing. Good luck to you!

Another important link to get started

[Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```