# Preparing a button for Onclick() listener

Tags: android, onclick

I am having errors when attempting to add an onclick listener button to my current code. The original post where I found the code is listed below. Your assistance is greatly appreciated. I am comfortable with Java but still  have trouble navigating with the Eclipse application. If anyone has any documentation that could help better prepare me that would be helpful.

[android eclipse button OnClick event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376970/android-eclipse-button-onclick-event)

MainActivity.java

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            myClick(v); /* my method to call new intent or activity */
        }
    });

    public void myClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(**this, Swipe.class**);
        startActivity(intent);// for calling the activity
    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.apptest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.apptest.MainActivityAppTest"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
    android:name=".Swipe"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
</activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What is exaclty your problem??

Comment: remove all * from line --->Intent intent = new Intent(**this, Swipe.class**);

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting a compilation error right?

In this line `Intent intent = new Intent(**this, Swipe.class**);`

You should type `Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Swipe.class);`

that should work